# load a random html with ajax on page load

Tags: ajax, random, load

I'm looking for a way to load in a random html file from 3 html files with ajax  into a main html page whenever the page is refreshed. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];

var randomUrl = urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length )];

$('body').load(randomUrl);
```

Have in mind that you may run into cross domain request policy issues. This means that you cannot load using ajax pages from others domain unless a special header is sent from the external hosts.

Alternatively you can redirect the page to the new one:

```
window.location = randomUrl;
```